# How to select text from Navigation Spinner on ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

I have `Navigation Spinner` on my Activity's `ActionBar`. It was populated by data from `SQLite Database` using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. 
I have done this using following code

```
String query="select rowid _id, vehicleName from vehiclesTable";
    try{
        Cursor c1=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (c1.getCount()>0){
         while (c1.moveToNext()){
             adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c1,new String[]{"vehicleName"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
         }
        }
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter,this);
```

Now I have to get the selected items text and display it in `Toast`. I don't know how to do that. Anyone who knows please help me with it.

Comment: Um, why are you looping through the cursor and creating a new adapter for each element?

Comment: because my cursor has more than one values

Comment: the CursorAdapter will use all the data available in the cursor, you're essentially creating multiple adapters and throwing them away, only the last one is used... you only need to do it once.

Comment: ok understood. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, instead of just rambling in comments; you should read the data from the Cursor from the same position as your Spinner is currently set to.

Something like

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, int id) {
    Cursor c = adapter.getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("vehicleName"));
    // show toast
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected item's text like this.

```
String selectedItemText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
```

then display selectedItemText in toast.

I hope it helps!